# Automatic Login using urllib2 python on a DLINK router

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

I would like to use urlllib to be connected automatically to my DLINK DIR 600 router

But I have some troubles ...

First this is the login form of the DLINK homepage :

```
<div class="message">Login to the router : </div>
    <div class="loginbox">
    <span class="name">User Name</span>
    <span class="delimiter">:</span>
    <span class="value">
    <input type="text" id="loginusr" onkeydown="BODY.OnKeydown(event);" />
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="loginbox">
    <span class="name">Password</span>
    <span class="delimiter">:</span>
    <span class="value">
    <input type="password" id="loginpwd" maxlength="15" onkeydown="BODY.OnKeydown(event);" />
    <input type="button" id="noGAC" value="Login" onClick="BODY.LoginSubmit();" />
    </span>
</div>
```

By default, the login is admin and there is no password

So I search on stackoverflow website and I made this code (with urllib) :

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://192.168.16.1'
values = {'loginusr' : 'admin',
      'loginpwd' : ''}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()

opener = urllib2.build_opener(
 urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
 urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
 urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
 urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies))

response = opener.open(url, data)
the_page = response.read()
http_headers = response.info()
```

I also try with requests lib as

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
login_data = dict(loginusr='admin', loginpwd='')
s.post('http://192.168.16.1', data=login_data)
```

But it doesn't work...

What type of mistake have I done ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever tried the requests library? Its much more readible than urllib, so its much easier to program. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ Maybe it will help you with your problem.

Comment: Yes I have tried but without success